# Turning off "server explorer" in vs2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, server-explorer

My vs2019 keeps hanging due to the "server explorer" connections which don't have usernames/passwords in them. I don't want to store the u/p in the web.config, so server explorer tries to connect, then finally times out.

I can delete those connections from server explorer, but they show up again when the project is rebuilt. I cannot figure out a way to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. My current workaround is to set "Connection Timeout=1;" in all connection strings from web.config/s. It doesn't fix problem itself but lowers freeze duration.